# Elasticsearch upgrade path from transport client to high level REST client

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

What is the upgrade path for an application using the Elasticsearch native Java client API (`TransportClient`) to move to using the high-level REST client for Java?

Documentation (preliminary?) seems to indicate:

> The Java High Level REST Client depends on the Elasticsearch core
>   project. It accepts the same request arguments as the TransportClient
>   and returns the same response objects.

(Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/5.x/java-rest-high.html)

But I am not entirely clear what this means. Will I be able to switch my entire codebase over to the high level REST client without rewriting my queries, or other client-type operations? It doesn't seem like the REST client implements the [`Client`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/Client.java) interface. That may make sense from a decoupling point-of-view.'

What I need to know is whether I should be building my own abstraction around client operations, or whether [`HighLevelRestClient`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/client/rest-high-level/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/RestHighLevelClient.java) will be basically implementing the `Client` interface already.

Should I continue, for the time being, to write code against the TransportClient API or will that code all need to be rewritten when TransportClient is deprecated?

Note that I am looking at the high-level REST client, not the low-level REST client.

Comment: one question I had while answering was: why do you need your own abstractions if the client object doesn't implement the existing `Client` interface?

Comment: @javanna I have an existing codebase that uses TransportClient and I need to write new code as well. I'd like to avoid having to make scattered changes all over the codebase. If the requests/responses are the same, it might make sense for me to create an object that uses those objects and passes to one of those two clients. It doesn't seem like the rest client is complete/mature enough to use yet; is that not true?

Comment: I would invest time in migrating to the high level REST client as soon as possible, rather than building an abstraction layer on top of the two clients. I would have a look at which API you need to use and see what is missing in the new client, then maybe wait for those to be added. You can open github issues for the next APIs that you would like to see supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The high level REST client doesn't implement the `Client` interface. The plan is described in this [blogpost](https://www.elastic.co/blog/state-of-the-official-elasticsearch-java-clients) that I wrote a while ago.

We are also in the process of writing documentation, which will contain a page with instructions on how to migrate from the transport client.

The new client reuses requests and responses from the existing transport client, but the client object is not compatible, that means that for instance the following:

```
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("index", "type", "id");
indexRequest.source("field", "value");
IndexResponse indexResponse = transportClient.index(indexRequest).get();
```

will become something like:

```
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("index", "type", "id");
indexRequest.source("field", "value");
IndexResponse indexResponse = restHighLevelClient.index(indexRequest);
```

As for async requests, the call is slightly different (see the method name), in the new client we went for a different method with a name that ends with the "Async" suffix, you would go from the following:

```
transportClient.index(indexRequest, new ActionListener<IndexResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(IndexResponse indexResponse) {
                        // called when the operation is successfully completed
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                        // called on failure
                    }
                });
```

to the following:

```
restHighLevelClient.indexAsync(indexRequest, new ActionListener<IndexResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(IndexResponse indexResponse) {
                    // called when the operation is successfully completed
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                    // called on failure
                }
            });
```

Unfortunately the `Client#prepare*` methods won't be available in the high level client, so something like:

```
IndexResponse indexResponse = transportClient.prepareIndex("index", "type", "id").setSource("field", "value").get();
```

needs to be migrated to the above using `ActionRequest`s rather then `ActionRequestBuilder`s. We are making this change as there was always confusion between requests and builders in the transport client, two ways of doing exactly the same thing. The new client will have a single way to provide requests.

If you want to have a look at the current documentation, it is already live although work in progress: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html .

The High Level REST Client will replace the Transport Client, although its first upcoming release will only support index, bulk, get, delete, update, search, search scroll and clear scroll APIs. Support for missing APIs will come next, we are also open to contributions from users as usual.

The Transport Client will be soon deprecated, hence I would advice to move over the the High Level REST Client as soon as possible, it shouldn't be a huge change and it will pay off as we will be improving it overtime, already going through REST is a great improvement.